# Test if a word is singular or plural in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, pluralize, singular

Quick question.

How can I test a word to see if it is singular or plural?

I'd really like:

```
test_singularity('word') # => true
test_singularity('words') # => false
```

I bet rails is capable!

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well in rails, you can do a `string#singularize|#pluralize` comparison to return a true or false value.

But I would think due to the nature of language itself, this might need some backup to do be completely accurate.

You could do something like this

```
def test_singularity(str)
  str.pluralize != str && str.singularize == str
end
```

But to see how accurate, I ran a quick set of words.

```
%w(word words rail rails dress dresses).each do |v|
  puts "#{v} : #{test_singularity(v)}"
end

word : true
words : false
rail : true
rails : false
dress : false
dresses : false
```

I was a little surprised actually, since 'dress' does get pluralized properly, but when it goes through the #singularize it runs into a bit of a snag.

```
'dress'.pluralize # => dresses
'dress'.singularize # => dres
```

Comment: The "dress".singularize issue is solved here: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2399-incorrect-inflectors-for-business-or-ness#ticket-2399-5

Answer (score 9):

Most of the times i never test for singularity or plural, i just convert it to the singular or plural form i require.

In **Rails 2.3.x** this was possible, writing something like this

```
plural_form = org_word.singularize.pluralize
singular_form = org_word.pluralize.singularize
```

Working further on this, a working function is easy to supply:

```
require 'active_support'

def is_singular?(str)
  str.pluralize.singularize == str
end


%w(word words rail rails dress dresses).each do |v|
  puts "#{v} : #{is_singular?(v)}"
end
```

which gives the following output:

```
word : true
words : false
rail : true
rails : false
dress : true
dresses : false
```

In **Rails 4**, with the given words, it is now much easier. You can just do

```
plural_form = org_word.pluralize
singular_form = org_word.singularize
```

and thus the function becomes much easier as well:

```
require 'active_support'

def is_singular?(str)
  str.singularize == str
end
```

Comment: The "dress".singularize issue is solved here: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2399-incorrect-inflectors-for-business-or-ness#ticket-2399-5

Comment: Inflectors make sure that the plural or singular can be defined for difficult cases. For instance: for valve it is necessary. But most of the times you only want to singularize and pluralize models? So those cases will be corrected already (or your routes would be messed up). But my routine did return the right answer for dress/dresses.

Comment: Why do you cast to plural first?

Comment: At the time this was the failsafe way, for me, to get the correct form. I haven't tried this in current rails. Did you see how old this answer is? :)

Comment: I tried in rails 4 and updated my answer accordingly. You are right @Simon, it is no longer needed.

Comment: Haha, I hadn't actually looked at the date, still helpful to me though!

Answer (score 1):

Neither ruby nor rails come with a specific method for testing for "plurality" on words.

As nowk said, the most you can do is implement them yourself, comparing with `word.pluralize` and `word.singularize`. This will give you a quick-and-cheap-and-generally-good way of testing. It will fail some times, though.

If you need more precision, you will need to use the [Ruby Linguistics gem](http://www.deveiate.org/projects/Linguistics/), which can deal with dress and dresses properly (but it's heavier).

Comment: actually, the singularize stuff isn't included by default on rails, but can be solved via an inflector. See my comments on other posts.